# Linux webserver tutorials (WordPress)

Tags: web-server, linux, lamp

I will be setting up a linux webserver to host WordPress on. The problem is that although I know how to do it, I don't know how to **properly** do it. So I'm now looking for semi-advanced tutorials that are **complete** and **secure** above anything else.

I don't really mind trying a new distro, but I prefer ubuntu/debian.

I read this post: [Any good resources for setting up a webserver in Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/77238/any-good-resources-for-setting-up-a-webserver-in-linux)
But these are very limited. So far not a lot of luck finding good guides and howtos.

This should probably be a community wiki but I can't seem to transform it myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One resource that I've used quite a bit is the [Debian 5.0 Tutorial on Rackspace](http://cloudservers.rackspacecloud.com/index.php/Debian_5.0_%28Lenny%29). It really helped me when I setup my first Debian webserver. I'm not sure if you are using a VPS or just simply using your own hardware, but most of the steps should be the same.

Comment: that looks like a really good resource, I'll take a closer look tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

This is also a very in depth resource:

http://www.lamphowto.com/